# How to detect the existence of Android Market on devices?

Tags: android, google-play

Some Android devices don't have Android Market, like Korea, etc.

Is it possible to detect the existence of Android Market at runtime?

I know I can try to open a market uri first to see if there is any exception thrown. But I don't think this is a wise approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know I can try to open a market uri
>   first to see if there is any exception
>   thrown.

Create the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` for the Market `Uri`, then use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see if you get anything back. If that returns an empty list, you know nothing on the device handles Market `Uri` values.

Comment: This is a good approach I hope all the programmers building third party stores handle the market URIs correct make their stores work as a real replacement to the google market.

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution, that also reads the packagename by itself ...

```
Context context = this;
final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

String packagename = this.getPackageName();

String url = "market://details?id=" + packagename;

Intent i2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i2.setData(Uri.parse(url));

List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i2,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

if (resolveInfo.size() > 0) startActivity(i2);
```