# Determine whether a device could launch Android Market app or not

Tags: android, exception, android-intent, google-play

I just wanted to "help" my users to give feedback to my app by providing a button to launch Market. Found a working solution here, of course, which does:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=<mypackagename>");
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Simple as that, thanks!

But: on my first run, I had that on my emulator. Gives an `ActivityNotFoundException` immediately.

Now, my question: is there a way to find out whether a call to this intent will succeed BEFORE I try it? That way I could hide the button completely to not even give the option.

Thanks for your much appreciated help!

Comment: The answer to this question will give you what you need
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341176/how-to-detect-the-existence-of-android-market-on-devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050068/check-if-intent-uri-is-available).

Instead of IMDB, use your market URL: `market://details?id=&lt;mypackagename>`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using this URL, you can use this one:

> https://market.android.com/details?id=<mypackagename>

Even if the user doesn't have the Market application, he could go to the Website.
If he has the Market application, he should have a prompt between Internet and Market.
[image]

BTW, surround your code with a try catch in case he has nothing ;o)

Comment: Yeah, that would work - but it does not look as nice as a direct jump... buuuuut, I could do this whenever I catch the exception! :)

Answer (score 0):

The exception was thrown just because there is no Android Market on the emulators. Every Android-powered device has the Android Market, so you shouldn't worry about this exception being thrown on a real device. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, there are real devices without a market. Of course the chance they get my app is small, but it is not impossible! :)